# vb.net How to subscribe to event that on a another class

Tags: vb.net, events

I have copied event example from net and trying to modify it, in this example i have win Form and two classes, form has a label and it should be update on event trigger. event raised on 3rd class, i want to know how to subscribe to event in a 3rd class from form.

this is a form class and it has subscribe to PercentDone event in widget class

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime

Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents mWidget As widget

    Private mblnCancel As Boolean

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        mWidget = New widget
       
    End Sub

    Private Sub mWidget_PercentDone(Percent As Single, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles mWidget.PercentDone
        If Me.lblPercentDone.InvokeRequired Then

        Else
            lblPercentDone.Text = CInt(100 * Percent) & "%"
        End If


        My.Application.DoEvents()
        If mblnCancel Then Cancel = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        mblnCancel = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ct As New Testclass
        mblnCancel = False
        lblPercentDone.Text = "0%"
        lblPercentDone.Refresh()
        ct.Callsubclx()
        '  mWidget.LongTask(12.2, 0.33)
        If Not mblnCancel Then lblPercentDone.Text = CStr(100) & "%"
    End Sub
End Class
```

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Testclass
    Public WithEvents mWidget As widget
    Private mblnCancel As Boolean

    Public Sub Callsubclx()
       
        mblnCancel = False
        Dim mWidget = New widget
        mWidget.LongTask(12.2, 0.33)
    End Sub


End Class
```

```
Public Class widget
    Public Event PercentDone(ByVal Percent As Single,
                             ByRef Cancel As Boolean)


    Public Sub LongTask(ByVal Duration As Single,
                    ByVal MinimumInterval As Single)
        Dim Threshold As Single
        Dim Start As Single
        Dim blnCancel As Boolean
        Console.WriteLine("Widget Thread=" & Thread.CurrentThread.Name)
        ' The Timer property of the DateAndTime object returns the seconds
        ' and milliseconds that have passed since midnight.
        Start = CSng(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Timer)
        Threshold = MinimumInterval

        Do While CSng(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Timer) < (Start + Duration)
            ' In a real application, some unit of work would
            ' be done here each time through the loop.
            If CSng(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Timer) > (Start + Threshold) Then
                RaiseEvent PercentDone(
                Threshold / Duration, blnCancel)


                ' Check to see if the operation was canceled.
                If blnCancel Then Exit Sub
                Threshold = Threshold + MinimumInterval
            End If


        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Firstly, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with the emphasis on the "minimal" in this case. There's way more there than is necessary to demonstrate your issue. Everything that's irrelevant in your question makes it harder for us to answer and thus more time-consuming. That's a waste of our time and it also makes it less likely that we'll answer at all, which is bad for you.

Comment: Also, please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. The number of classes is irrelevant. It's the relationship between the objects that matters. I suspect that you're saying, without actually saying that you have class A which creates an instance of class B and that creates an instance of class C, then you want the A object to handle an event raised by the C object. Is that correct?

Comment: Does this code contain your two different attempts at doing the same thing? Testclass seems unnecessary

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes that what i want to do.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case where an instance of class `A` creates an instance of class `B` and that creates an instance of class `C`, then you want `A` to respond to an event in `C`, you have three options:

1. `B` passes `A` a reference to `C` and then `A` handles the event as normal.
2. `A` creates a delegate for the event and passes that to `B`, which attaches it to the event.
3. `B` handles the event in `C` and raises its own event that is handled by `A`.

I will provide an example of each case.

Example of case 1:

```vb
Public Class ClassA

    Private WithEvents c As ClassC

    Private Sub c_SomethingHappened(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles c.SomethingHappened
        '...
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateB()
        Dim b As New ClassB

        c = b.C
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ClassB

    Public Property C As ClassC

    Public Sub New()
        C = New ClassC()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ClassC

    Public Event SomethingHappened As EventHandler

End Class
```

Example of case 2:

```vb
Public Class ClassA

    Private Sub HandleSomethingHappened(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        '...
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateB()
        Dim b As New ClassB(AddressOf HandleSomethingHappened)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ClassB

    Private c As New ClassC

    Public Sub New(somethingHappenedHandler As EventHandler)
        AddHandler c.SomethingHappened, somethingHappenedHandler
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ClassC

    Public Event SomethingHappened As EventHandler

End Class
```

Example of case 3:

```vb
Public Class ClassA

    Private WithEvents b As New ClassB

    Private Sub b_SomethingHappened(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b.SomethingHappened
        '...
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ClassB

    Private WithEvents c As New ClassC

    Public Event SomethingHappened As EventHandler

    Private Sub c_SomethingHappened(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles c.SomethingHappened
        OnSomethingHappened(EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnSomethingHappened(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent SomethingHappened(Me, e)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ClassC

    Public Event SomethingHappened As EventHandler

End Class
```